# How many nodes elastic search creates on single machine by defaults

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I have ELK setup. with elastic search version 2.3.x. I wanted to know how many nodes by default it should create. I have noticed a weird situation. When I restarted elastic search it started with 3 nodes. There are multiple folder in data path ( /var/lib/elasticsearch/0 , 1 , 2 ,3). But when I restart it again it took only one node. I wanted to know how it is defining a number of nodes.

```
# curl -s -XGET "http://localhost:9200/_cat/nodes?v"
```

Because of this many shared are showing un-assigned due to lack of nodes

Comment: The multiple folders you see are the shard folders. Each index has 5 shards by default, so you should have 5 sub-folders in each index folder. But those folders are not data from different nodes.

Comment: these are not shard folder.  shard folder path is  inside index folder. "/var/lib/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/nodes/0/indices/filebeat-2019.02.25"

Answer (score 1):

Your single elasticsearch installation on one machine is one node, if you want to have more u need to have multiple elastic installations running. See [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-node.html) for further details.

Comment: Thanks, I can understand it will create a single node. But somehow before elastic search restart, it created three nodes.  root@KibanaServer:/var/lib/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/nodes# ls
0  1  2  3

Comment: If u start the elasticsearch process more then once one the same machine u will have more then one node.